# Not sending data to Web Service

Tags: c#, web-services, xaml, windows-phone-8

Here's my code for sending the data. There is a string strJson i want to send the string data to the service reference i have integrated.

```
ServiceReference3.Service1Client client = new ServiceReference3.Service1Client();
client.GetOrderAsync(strJson);
```

It throws Following Exception:An exception of type

> 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException' occurred in
>   System.ServiceModel.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Exception place:It opens reference.cs and in that at this code it throws following exception.

An exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

```
public bool EndGetOrder(System.IAsyncResult result) 
 {
    object[] _args = new object[0];
    bool _result=((bool)(base.EndInvoke("GetOrder", _args, result)));//At this line exception occurs
    return _result;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var c = new HttpClient
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri("Your URL")
};

c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

var json = "Your json string"

var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "Your Method name in URI Template")
{
    Content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
};
c.SendAsync(req).ContinueWith(respTask =>
{
    var response = respTask.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Console.WriteLine("Response: {0}", respTask.Result);
});
}
```