# Dynamically created grid not showing

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

First I have given column definition to the main grid in which I dynamically want grids to be created:

```
public void create_grid()
{
  ColumnDefinition colDef11 = new ColumnDefinition();

  ColumnDefinition colDef22 = new ColumnDefinition();

  ColumnDefinition colDef33 = new ColumnDefinition();
  LayoutRoot.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef11);
  LayoutRoot.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef22);
  LayoutRoot.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef33);
}
```

Then I am creating the grid:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
  for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
  {
    Grid mygrid = new Grid() { Height = 250, Width = 432 };
    mygrid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Aqua);

    string k = "gdr" + h ;
    mygrid.Name = k;
    _grid.Add(k, mygrid);
    tb_id_copy.Add(h);

    LayoutRoot.Children.Add(mygrid);

    Grid.SetColumn(mygrid, j);
    Grid.SetRow(mygrid, i);

    h++;
    r++;
  }
  RowDefinition rowDefj1 = new RowDefinition() ;
  LayoutRoot.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDefj1);
}
```

But only two rows of grid are created anyhow.Total nine grids are created but they overlap each other.I have attached screenshot below of the grids created.

[image: image of grids being created]

Comment: How do u knw that it overlaps only?

Comment: tb_id_copy.Add(h); at this code i am adding int value to list .And when i check its length it shows me 0 to 8 that means 9 grids are created.Also i kept debugger to check the same.

Comment: What have u tried to make row's height less or auto?

Comment: i haven't tried anything but i implemented a scroll viewer.

Comment: If u have tried to give some int values it might have shown error that cannot convert int to GridLength

Comment: Yeah i just tried that and it shows the same error u said.So any solution for it?

Comment: I am trying. wait for sometime

Comment: Your outer for loop says `for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)`. That's only two values, and it is what you use here: `Grid.SetRow(mygrid, i);`. Also, the `LayoutRoot.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDefj1);` is executed only twice. Why do you expect three rows?

Comment: yah i got it. Thanks Kris and Rooney.

Comment: watch above comment of @KrisVandermotten

Comment: And can you please solve this question ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23261354/not-sending-data-to-web-service

Comment: Please try to solve this question . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23261354/not-sending-data-to-web-service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your outer for loop says `for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)`. That's only two values, and it is what you use here: `Grid.SetRow(mygrid, i);`. Also, the `LayoutRoot.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDefj1);` is executed only twice.

It should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
```